# I Have an error and im stuck int his error : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using Android Studio and Firebase for a social media app and I am stuck in this error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached skipping layout

I saw a lot of questions on Stack Overflow but it didn't help me solve my problem. Is this may be a problem with Firebase ? Queries Thanks for all the help you will give me.

My UsersFragment.java

```java
package com.adamdevmaster.flintblog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterUsers adapterUsers;
    List<ModelUser> userList;

    public UsersFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.users_recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        userList = new ArrayList<>();

        getAllUsers();

        return view;
    }

    private void getAllUsers() {
        final FirebaseUser fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelUser modelUser = ds.getValue(ModelUser.class);

                    if (!modelUser.getUid().equals(fUser.getUid())) {
                        userList.add(modelUser);
                    }

                    adapterUsers = new AdapterUsers(getActivity(), userList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsers);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ModelUser.java

```java
    String name, email, search, phone, image, cover, uid;

    public ModelUser() {
    }

    public ModelUser(String name, String email, String search, String phone, String image, String cover, String uid) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.search = search;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.image = image;
        this.cover = cover;
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCover() {
        return cover;
    }

    public void setCover(String cover) {
        this.cover = cover;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
```

My AdapterUsers.java

```java
package com.adamdevmaster.flintblog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class AdapterUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUsers.MyHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ModelUser> userList;

    public AdapterUsers(Context context, List<ModelUser> userList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
        String userImage = userList.get(i).getImage();
        String userName = userList.get(i).getName();
        final String userEmail = userList.get(i).getEmail();

        myHolder.mNameTv.setText(userName);
        myHolder.mEmailTv.setText(userEmail);
        try {
            Picasso.get().load(userImage)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_img)
                    .into(myHolder.mAvatarIv);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView mAvatarIv;
        TextView mNameTv, mEmailTv;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mAvatarIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarIv);
            mNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
            mEmailTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailTv);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the viewgroup context not activity context

```
LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_listitem, viewGroup, false);
```

Comment: Thank you but it was just a problem with firebase so the problem is solved.